# Query MySQL for current and day old data, compute change

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am building an application that I can most easily describe as a Stock Market data tracking app (it's not exactly that).

I have a table called 'market_cache'. Every 10 minutes, a script loads that table with the most recent market data, making a new row for each stock symbol (and leaves a timestamp, of course). I'm tracking 114 stock symbols, therefore, each time this script is executed, 114 new rows are added (with a timestamps within a second or two of each other).

I'm aiming to build a table that lists all of these stocks with their current data and a 24-hour % change, so in oder to compute the change, I need a second query that pulls the same data, but from 1 day ago.

Here are the queries I'm using:

For the most recent set of data:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(sym), trade_to, name, marketid, lasttrade, volume, cachetime FROM market_cache WHERE cachetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 114
```

I'm using the DISTINCT(sym) call to make sure that the same stock symbol isn't pulled up twice in the same query, and setting the time interval to ensure I only get the rows that have been written in the last 10 minutes. This query appears to work exactly as I want it to.

My second query, to pull the change data, looks like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(sym), trade_to, name, marketid, lasttrade, volume, cachetime FROM market_cache WHERE cachetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1450 MINUTE ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 114
```

This query is almost identical to the one above, except the interval, 1450 minutes (10 day + 10 minutes), is different. This query, however, does not work, and it only produces the first stock symbol (1 result).

If I try to pull data for just ONE stock symbol and get day-old data for that symbol to compute the % change, I can do that no problem. However, I'm running into trouble trying to query for all 114 stocks at once, and then another set of the same 114 stocks from a day ago.

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: try this "INTERVAL '10 0:10:0' DAY_SECOND". maybe the 1450 is the problem

Comment: I don't think that's it.  Your suggestion and the original interval are the same thing.  If you run this query, you get 0.  SELECT now() - interval 1450 MINUTE = now() - interval '10 0:10:0' DAY_SECOND;

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your query:

in your first query you write

> WHERE **cache time** >= NOW()

and then in your second query it's

> WHERE **cachetime** >= NOW()

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing it out. But actually, the typo happened in my browser window, when I was retyping the query (thanks auto-correct), but it was represented correctly in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your 'where' clause wrong?

Don't you want something like this:

```
WHERE cachetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1450 MINUTE
      and cachetime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1440 MINUTE
```

Comment: I had actually tried that syntax and I kept getting 0 results from the query. Inspired by this answer, though, I decided to change the WHERE clause to: WHERE cachetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1450 MINUTE
      and cachetime <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I often get confused with subtracting/adding/less than/greater than on dates and times.  If you do too, the trick is to add it to your SELECT clause.  So in your query (or a separate query), you can type SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1450 MINUTE to see what is actually being calculated.  You can also do TIMEDIFF.  SELECT TIMEDIFF(cachetime, NOW()-INTERVAL 1450 MINUTE) to see what that returns.  You may need a semi-colon at the end of the SELECT.